# CLION - Qt requires c++11 support

Tags: c++, qt, clion

I use Clion & Cmake for my project.

This is my CMake-File:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION  3.16.3)
project(Target123)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake")

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)

add_executable(
        Target123
        main.cpp
        startscreen.cpp startscreen.h startscreen.ui)

set_target_properties(Target123
        PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
        )

target_link_libraries (Target123
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Gui
        Qt5::Widgets)
```

(As you can see, I tried on multiple occasions to fix the versioning problem)

When the compiler gets to a file including QT-Modules, the following error is printed:

```
msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:61:4: error: #error "Qt requires C++11 support"
 #  error "Qt requires C++11 support"
    ^
```

I've read a lot on stackoverflow in order to fix this problem, but nothing helped yet.

//UPDATE:
Changing the version to CXX_STANDARD 14 didn't change a thing

Comment: If you are using MSVC, it doesn't have a C++11 option. Try C++14 instead.

Comment: @BoP I tried it, doesn't work - same error occurs.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: If you're using msvc then you shouldn't get this message. If you aren't then you've downloaded the wrong build of Qt, you need to get one for your compiler (and possibly get a more up to date compiler)

Comment: How did you configured your project with cmake?